# How to explain to TypeScript that method is augmented if not replaced

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

The problem is that I want to use a decorated method which retrieves a property from a decorator which in its turn receives method's arguments makes some stuff and calls the decorated method with results of this stuff.

Here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkojji

```
export function Augment(
  target: any,
  propertyKey: string,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) {
  const method = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = function(message: string) {
    return method.call(this, {
      data: message
    });
  };
  return descriptor;
}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  @Augment
  decorated(data: string) {
    return data.data;
  }

  replacedMethod(val: string) {
    console.log(val);
    return val;
  }
}
```

Here in function `Augment` I catch the arguments and apply the results of a calculation (here for the sake of simplicity it's simply a wrapping in an object) to the decorated method.

The problem is that TypeScript is sure that method is called with `string` meanwhile it receives `object`. TypeScript compilator complaints about this, however the code itself is working. I don't want to suppress all decorator calls.

All these efforts are actually for simplifying API calls to make something like

```
@Post
users(data: any): Observable<any> {
  return data.pipe(
    mapTo(null)
  );
}
```

And call it somewhere `users({page: 1})`. So that decorator takes `users` as an endpoint path, calls it with payload provided to `users` and executes `users` with `http.post` so that `users` now is a pipeable operator.

Comment: Decorators in TypeScript [do not mutate types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881), so you can't do this.  You might be able to refactor to use [class expressions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#extending-expressions) and [subclassing](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#extending-expressions) them instead of using decorators.

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially not possible to do this with decorators, as decorators [do not mutate the types of the things they decorate (see microsoft/TypeScript#4881)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881).  So if you're decorating a method taking a `string` parameter, the compiler will still see it as a method taking a `string` parameter, even if you've changed it at runtime.  There's plenty of discussion in microsoft/TypeScript#4881 about it, with strong feelings on both sides, but ultimately it's [unlikely anything will change in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881#issuecomment-450938639) until [the analogous proposed JavaScript feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) is mature enough to be stable.

---

Instead, you might want to think about using a decorator-like function which takes the class constructor with one method, and converts it into another class constructor with the augmented method.  It's just "like" a decorator because you don't use it with the `@` notation; instead you use it like a [class expression](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#extending-expressions) and [subclass](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#extending-expressions) it. It's more straightforward to replace *class* decorators with class expressions, but you can also do it with method decorators with a bit more effort.

Here's an example.  Note that the following code is *just* an example; it hasn't been fully tested and it might not behave as you desire in all cases.  It does a lot of type juggling and type assertions to appease the compiler:

```
type AugmentMethod<
  T extends Record<K, (...args: any) => any>,
  K extends keyof T,
  A extends readonly any[]> = { [P in keyof T]:
    P extends K ? (...args: A) => ReturnType<T[P]> : T[P]
  };

function AugmentMethod<
  C extends new (...args: any) => Record<K, (...args: any) => any>,
  T extends InstanceType<C>,
  K extends keyof any,
  A extends readonly any[],
  >(
    ctor: C,
    methodName: K,
    wrapMethod: (...args: A) => Readonly<Parameters<T[K]>>
  ) {

  return class extends (ctor as any) {
    constructor(...args: any) {
      super(...args);
    }
    [methodName](...args: A) {
      return super[methodName](...(wrapMethod(...args) as any[]));
    }
  } as (new (...args: ConstructorParameters<C>) => AugmentMethod<T, K, A>) &
    { [P in keyof C]: P extends "prototype" ? AugmentMethod<T, K, A> : C[P] };
}
```

So the type `AugmentMethod` takes three type parameters: a "base" class instance type `T`, a method name `K` for the class, and a new parameter list type `A` for that method.  It returns the type of the "sub" class instance type, whose properties are the same as those of `T`, except that the method named `K` takes parameters of type `A`.

And the function `AugmentMethod` takes three parameters: a "base" class *constructor* value which constructs instances of type `T`, a method name of type `K` for the class, and a parameter wrapping function which takes parameters of type `A` and returns an ordered array of parameters to be passed to the "base" class constructor.  And it returns a "sub" class constructor whose instances are `AugmentMethod<T, K, A>`: the same as the "base" instance except that its augmented method expects a set of arguments to be passed to the parameter wrapping function above.

Here's something like your example code:

```
class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  decorated(data: { data: string }) {
    console.log("Got " + JSON.stringify(data));
    return data.data;
  }

  replacedMethod(val: string) {
    console.log(val);
    return val;
  }
}

const a = new AppComponent();
const sa = a.decorated({ data: "hi" }); // Got {"data":"hi"};
console.log(sa); // hi
```

So the `AppComponent` class is unchanged and its `decorated()` method expects a parameter of type `{data: string}`.  Let's use the `AugmentMethod` class expression:

```
class WrappComponent extends
  AugmentMethod(AppComponent, "decorated", (data: string) => [{ data }] as const) { }

const w = new WrappComponent();
const sw = w.decorated("hey"); // Got {"data":"hey"};
console.log(sw); // hey
```

So you can see that `WrappComponent` is now acting like a version of `AppComponent` whose `decorated()` method has been "decorated" by the `AugmentMethod` function.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggrgcwLYQHbALIWACwPYAmAPAFBRQAqUEAHsGgQM5QBKEAxngE7EDSANFAAUAOjEBDLgkYAuKONQgAlFAC8APnmL1-MlF7U6DZgGsIIPADNKu8jEP1UTKFwjiCeVABsQWkAG0AXU1VKABvKH8ABSgAS1QoMwtrCkCZPXIY2kdnAwB+YTERSWk5GBUNVmw4LlQKcAgiCmjgqDlmqMC9AF8AbhISSzhUdmBYz1hEFHQsXEJScgBhB2MoVAgAd0KJKVk-Cs02Th4iAW3i3bkFZTVNa509KmzVgElURmAFdgh6yCJFh7kAzPJymcxWPy2WArUEuNweby+a5BKHqIQZKCjbhyRZQ8goOYEABy4hQcgEGI2XHEYFm+AIclEO1KsAOVXcnh8RCiklJ2AgXEYTX8vGC6j0KjCA3IrmANQS7C84kYzBBziEWK48mY10lGM472AXDgmqZFxZuvCGPIjDgkC4ZpKjCU-XI5G6GP8BPpJJQgUdl1ZVrdbtl8qgtvtXuwPr5-qKQipNLphAD0hUyr8QSULoxHvd2uE6y2ab2i08H2Nmp51IJAqFALZ8GQaEwMfmFEEZxg6hUADIMRFonEEkkIYs0lAskZYQAiMBcPDAJcNWdQArN6ZtwlNLuCHttKCLFpQPokD0DRXK5gwMBgctIMCeVvBtZ8tRQWcwVAIOBKrizv0egEBw3DiPQBBCAQ4HiHIETQZ8ciVvECCnnqIYGoweBeBAIheHgCBCLOADiS6flAADUUAAFIAMoAPJEiIyE-rElggFBME5q6obVLUUAIeIIiCTxF4yhAYBKt8BAppBABu4heEhRooehbqYdhuH4YRCleLmIZhvxumieel4VsA8gfsWsB3g+T7rOgQi5phFmMOIH5CSBxzgRAkHwTBcizjgsRrt0LpQAA9BFUCkRZYSzoJs4yEFIVnhpOF4QRQhueFUVQMFAwkFeKpQAA6tStl4I+z7oDCTB6JurayUIt73lV9mtoICWgdSEGzoInGIRGKk-my-j+Z8p6BIWLmSqeZmGlAWyhNZ5U0m11UOcATn9C5EbLUtwk9T5kFBeYs65dFsXhAlMFJWdICzmlFaaZlhGMBsl35eYhVAA)